# Have more than 2 concurrent VPN connection to a Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I am trying to have 10 PCs to concurrently connect to my windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise via L2TP VPN. The problem that I am facing now is that after connecting 2 PCs via VPN, a third one cannot connect at all. I have tried disconnecting all VPN connection and used the third PC's and its account to connect. It works.

I am using window's "Routing and Remote Access" for the L2TP VPN.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. I have too little IP addresses for the the VPN. All I need to do is to increase the IP range to be made available